# Use Raspberry Pi as a bluetooth "headset"

Tags: android, python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, a2dp

I is it possible to Connect the Pi Over Bluetooth to a phone and use the Pi as Microphone Input and Audio Output? 
Thanks in Advance